# How and why is support vector machine training affected (or not) by addition/removal of points

Tags: svm

I see sources saying the hyperplane after training only depends on the support vectors, and removing non-support vectors before training will have no effect on the hyperplane after training on what's left.

If that's true, I suppose training would have been sped up if we didn't train on non-support vectors.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to identify non support vectors and remove them before training to speed up training? Maybe there are heuristics on which rows are more likely to be the support vectors, so we can keep them only for faster training?
2. If the first paragraph is true, that means adding new datapoints that are not support vectors, then training again will have no impact on the hyperplane? This doesn't feel right because this means we're stuck with the same model forever no matter what new data arrives.
3. How do points become support vectors (SV)? Are they SV only because the other points are not SV, meaning all points must be considered together in an optimization process? But this contradicts first paragraph saying you can remove some non SV before training and still get the same hyperplane, making me think who is SV is independent of who is non SV.

Can anyone identify the errors in my thought process. I'm confused about the relationship between SV and non SV, and how their identities of SV/non SV change with new points. I may also have unclear concepts of what's going on during training vs prediction.